# Prove that if ax+by=c has an integer solution, then it has infinitely many integer solutions (x, y) where x is even or y is even.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, congruences, gcd-and-lcm

Full question : Let a, b and c be non-zero integers.  Prove that if ax+by=c has an integer solution, then it has infinitely  many  integer  solutions  (x, y)  where x is  even  or  it  has  infinitely  many  integer  solutions (x, y) where y is even.

I'm confused on how to prove this, using LDET1, i know that the gcd(a,b)=d and d must divide c.

Now if I take the first case where x is even in (x,y), i get 2 more cases,
when y is even and y is odd
case 1: i can put x=2k, y=2m and prove that d is still divisible by c, even after the substitution.
case 2: putting x=2k and y=(2l+1) i get something like d(2+b/d)=c, since b/d is an integer (d is gcd of a,b) 2+b/d is also an int and d/c in this case too.

Am i doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

If $ax+by=c$ for some $x$ and $y$, then for any integer $n$:

$a(x+nb)+b(y-na)=ax+abn+by-abn=ax+by=c$.

So, for any solution $(x,y)$, you can get infinitely many other solutions $(x+nb,y-na)$.

Note that this proof works whether $x$ or $y$ are even or not.